# Convert UL LI to multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having an indefinite number of lists, let's say 3:

```
<ul class="data-wrapper">
 <li class="item-name"><strong>Los Angeles</strong></li>
 <li class="item-lat">34.052235</li>
 <li class="item-lng">-118.243683</li>
</ul>

<ul class="data-wrapper">
 <li class="item-name"><strong>Santa Monica</strong></li>
 <li class="item-lat">34.024212</li>
 <li class="item-lng">-118.496475</li>
</ul>

<ul class="data-wrapper">
 <li class="item-name"><strong>Redondo Beach</strong></li>
 <li class="item-lat">33.849182</li>
 <li class="item-lng">-118.388405</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to get this Array:

```
(3) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]

0: Array(3)
0: "</strong>Los Angeles</strong>"
1: 34.052235
2: -118.243683

1: Array(3)
0: "</strong>Santa Monica</strong>"
1: 34.024212
2: -118.496475

2: Array(3)
0: "</strong>Redondo Beach</strong>"
1: 33.849182
2: -118.388405
```

I came up with this

```
var array_items = $('.data-wrapper li').remove().map(function () {
    return this;
}).get();

var array = [array_items];
```

Or this

```
var array = [];
$('.data-wrapper li').each(function(i, elem) {
    array.push($(elem).text());
});
```

But I'm not getting exactly what I need, including the coordinates as numbers, or to keep the `<strong>` tag

Comment: Yup, just a typo writing it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `.get()` with JS's [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const arr2D =
  $(".data-wrapper").get().map((el) => $(el).children().get().map(el => $(el).html()));

console.log(arr2D)
```

```html
<ul class="data-wrapper">
 <li class="item-name"><strong>Los Angeles</strong></li>
 <li class="item-lat">34.052235</li>
 <li class="item-lng">-118.243683</li>
</ul>

<ul class="data-wrapper">
 <li class="item-name"><strong>Santa Monica</strong></li>
 <li class="item-lat">34.024212</li>
 <li class="item-lng">-118.496475</li>
</ul>

<ul class="data-wrapper">
 <li class="item-name"><strong>Redondo Beach</strong></li>
 <li class="item-lat">33.849182</li>
 <li class="item-lng">-118.388405</li>
</ul>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Example using pure JS:**

```js
const EL_dataWrapper = document.querySelectorAll(".data-wrapper");
const arr2D = [...EL_dataWrapper].map(EL => [...EL.children].map(EL => EL.innerHTML));

console.log(arr2D);
```

```html
<ul class="data-wrapper">
 <li class="item-name"><strong>Los Angeles</strong></li>
 <li class="item-lat">34.052235</li>
 <li class="item-lng">-118.243683</li>
</ul>

<ul class="data-wrapper">
 <li class="item-name"><strong>Santa Monica</strong></li>
 <li class="item-lat">34.024212</li>
 <li class="item-lng">-118.496475</li>
</ul>

<ul class="data-wrapper">
 <li class="item-name"><strong>Redondo Beach</strong></li>
 <li class="item-lat">33.849182</li>
 <li class="item-lng">-118.388405</li>
</ul>
```

If you need only the *text value* use `EL.textContent` insetad of `EL.innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It actually worked fine :)
Now I'm wondering why is it adding a 4th element to the sub-arrays?

Comment: You're welcome :) @PaulRodríguez please run both the above examples . Do they work? There's no 4th element in array.

Comment: They do indeed! I'm just seeing a blank 4th element inside the arrays. It's not a biggie anyway, just wondering why :)

Comment: @PaulRodríguez could not know. I used your exact HTML. Perhaps in your document you forgot to close properly some `</li>` elements? or `</ul>` ? take a second check!

Comment: My bad, it was indeed a typo in my end. Thanks again! Super clean solution :)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You're welcome again, go build nice things! 